# Sequelize: How to undo migrations for dropped tables?

Tags: express, heroku, sequelize.js

In my Express Sequelize Postgres app, I created a migration to create a model/table with some attributes.

After the migration (status: up), I dropped the table.

Now I cannot undo the migration - the migration file exists, but I get the following error:

`ERROR: relation "public.CustomerAddresses" does not exist`

How do I undo the migration, so I can remigrate?

Comment: Why did you drop the table? You should never modify your database structure if you're using migrations (and you should always be using migrations). In any case, you can recreate the table manually (undoing the "drop table" you ran manually), then reverse the migration.

Comment: I introduced migrations after using db.sync, and wanted to start over with migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible options:

1. As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734510/sequelize-how-to-undo-migrations-for-dropped-tables#comment94323093_53734510), you can undo your manual drop by manually recreating the table.  As long as the table exists, you'll be able to undo your migration.
2. You can remove the entry for your migration from the migrations table to make the state of your schema match the state of the migrations table, since you've already performed the drop manually:

   ```
   DELETE FROM "SequelizeMeta" WHERE name='<your migration name>';
   ```

Comment: Option 2 may work in some circumstances (e.g. if the table creation was done in a single migration, and that migration didn't do anything else, and the table wasn't later modified in another migration, and it's the most recent migration). Option 1 is a more generic solution that should work every time, assuming we're just trying to undo a dropped table.